# how to configure multisupport dao using spring

Tags: java, spring-jdbc

For my application I want to use both Spring jdbc as well as orm technology like JPA or Hibernate, I have option in spring to configure either jpa , hirbernate or spring`s own jdbcTemplates. How can as I configure altogether and use as per need? A **MultiSupport Dao** kind of thing which should support all these jpa/hibernate and springs jdbc template???

Comment: how do you want to make the decision which to use?  At runtime, based on the data?  Or at compile time, based on the method called?

Answer (score 1):

This blog has a tutorial on mixing them :

http://hibernatebp.blogspot.co.uk/2012/02/mixing-spring-hibernate-jpa-and-plain.html

(including a great 'when whould you choose to do this?' discussion)